# Complement function

Tags: r, complement

**My data:**

```
a <- c('KK','LL','II','JJ','AA','CC','GG','FF','EE','QQ','ZZ','XX')
b <- c('CC','GG','FF','EE','KK','LL','II','JJ','QQ','ZZ','XX','BB','AA','OO','WW')
```

**target:**
list all of the things that which  「 "b"have but "a" don't have 」

**I try :**

```
union(a,b)

[1] "KK" "LL" "II" "JJ" "AA" "CC" "GG" "FF" "EE" "QQ" "ZZ" "XX" "BB" "OO"
[15] "WW"

intersect(a,b)

[1] "KK" "LL" "II" "JJ" "AA" "CC" "GG" "FF" "EE" "QQ" "ZZ" "XX"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the R language:

```
setdiff(b, a)
```

See also [the docs on set operations](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sets.html)